# How to implement nested REST to a auction listing resources?

Tags: rest

I'm trying to design a auction listings resources, with questions in each listing and a users who create the listing, I want to make it as semantic as possible, here's my implementation:

1. Create a new listing:

   `GET listings/new` # get the form, should it be more semantic using `GET listings?action` 
   `POST listings`
2. Retrieve a list of unanswered question on a single listing

   `GET listings/#id/questions?answered=False`
3. Retrieve the details of a single listing

   `GET listings/#id`
4. Answer a specific question

   `GET listings/#id/questions/#id` # the page content form to submit question

   `PUT listings/#id/questions/#id` #should I use POST instead?
5. Retrieve a list of unanswered questions for all listings belonging to a member

   `GET users/$id/questions?answered=False`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

- To create a new listing, you should rather do a POST on the /listings/ url.
- You did not indicate how you would get the actual answers